# How to retrieve custom field from User object using liveagent.chasitor.getDetails()

Tags: visualforce, liveagent

I have a VF page for my LiveAgent chat application. I am using the below JS code to retrieve UserId of the current user without querying.

```
try {
     var agentDetails = liveagent.chasitor.getDetails();
     var agentId = agentDetails.agent.userId;
    }
```

This works great. Now that, I would like to retrieve a specific custom field from the User object, is there a way to get it using the above approach? Like:

```
var agentField = agentDetails.agent.myField__c;
```

I am familiar with querying for the field value within Controller and make use of it, but I would like to limit my SOQLs for an efficient implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about the details when answering this but a Visualforce page will have access to the record using getRecord().

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_getRecord.htm

**Now** if I am hearing you **wrong**, the answer is you cannot per the linked documentation above.

Per documentation:
*Note that only the fields that are referenced in the associated Visualforce markup are available for querying on this SObject. **All other fields, including fields from any related objects, must be queried using a SOQL expression.***

Here's an example if your controller is right on the record itself, the simple example.

```
String agentRecordCustomField = (string)agentRecord.get('myField__c');

System.debug(agentRecordCustomField);
```

Here's an example for an Account controller:

```
Account acct = (Account)controller.getrecord();
String acctCustomField = (string)acct.get('Custom_Field__c');

System.debug(acctCustomField);
```